# Asynchronous coordinate grabbing before submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, post, promise

I'm trying to have a input field of a location be submitted, looked up via Google Geocoder for the latitude and longitude, put those on some hidden fields, and then posted as a form.

There are two main blockers, the first is that my validateFields function doesn't see the values added into the hidden text boxes, and the second one being delaying the submission of the form to add the long and lat as part of the post.

I know a can have the submit event return true or false to delay the submission based on the validateField check, but it never seems to see the coordinates even though using Chrome Dev Tools I see them added in.

```
$('#LocationSearchForm').submit(event => {
    let input = $('#SearchTerm').val();
    $('#Longitude'.val('23423'));
    $('#Latitude'.val('1111'));
    getLatLong().then(allowSubmit);
});

function getLatLong(input) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ address: input }, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#Latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#Longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            }
        });
        resolve(console.log(`applied coordinates to hidden fields`));
    });
}

function validateFields() {
    if ($('#Latitude').val() === '' && $('#Longitude').val() === '') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function allowSubmit() {
    return validateFields();
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="LocationSearchForm" action="POST">
    <input id="SearchTerm" type="text" placeholder="Find a city" value>
    <input id="Latitude" type="hidden" value>
    <input id="Longitude" type="hidden" value>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to return true or false from the event handler itself. It doesn't matter what the `allowSubmit` function returns. You will need to *always* prevent the form from submitting on  that event, then validate, then when it's ok submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys. For reference I got it working this way with the help of @charlietfl's answer.

```
$('#LocationSearchForm').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let input = $('#SearchTerm').val();

    getLatLong(input)
        .then(() => {
            return !validateFields() ? $('form')[0].submit() : null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

function getLatLong(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ address: input }, (results, status) => {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#Latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#Longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                reject(false);
            }
        });
    });
}

function validateFields() {
    return $('#Latitude').val() === '' && $('#Longitude').val() === '';
}
```

Using the 'this' wasn't working for me, but maybe because I was insistent of using arrow functions, would this be bad practice when mixing with jQuery? I tried `$('#LocationSearchForm')` and that wasn't working, so I had to use the `$('form')[0].submit()` instead, but I'm not sure if this is good practice to submit the form like this.

Thanks @Bergi for boolean return on submit suggestion, that seems like a good alternative way of delaying the submit compared to using an explicit `submit()` and `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to move the `resolve()` inside the `geocode` callback. Right now it is resolving immediately but `geocode()` is asynchronous.

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: input}, (results, status) => {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    $('#Latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
    $('#Longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
    // resolve now that data updated
    resolve(console.log(`applied coordinates to hidden fields`));
  } else {
    // reject here
  }
});
```

In the `submit` callback you need to prevent the immediate submit to allow time for the asynchronous operations. You can then use native submit once the promise resolves

```
$('#LocationSearchForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    let form = this;

    getLatLong().then(function(){
      if(validateFields()){
         // use native submit to by-pass jQuery listener
         form.submit()
      }else{
          // alert user of problems
      }
    }).catch(function(err){ /*do something for geocode rejection */});
});
```